# Which type of rvm install do I do if I want to use it with phusion passanger

Tags: rvm, passenger

I am on ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

I have installed apache2 running as www-data.

I want to use ruby 1.9.3.

I need to install passanger.

The question is which installation method should I use to install rvm.  Should I use the single-user or the multi-user installation.

If I have to use the single-user installation, do I install it as my user or as www-data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my production systems, I install RVM system-wide. That way I can log in (or anyone else can login) and pull up a console on the system using the same ruby and gemsets. I am sure there are ways to do that with single user, but this has always been the least complicated for me.

However, for Passenger, I recommend installing that against the system ruby. The reason for that is because every time you change or upgrade your ruby, it would blow up your passenger installation and you would need to change your Apache configuration and rerun the passenger installation. This works because passenger and your application do not need to run on the same ruby installation.